# How to add tableview xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am using Xcode 8.3.2. I am following https://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1, and it says to "add a table view".

I can't find it when I follow the steps. I also followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFpMiSsynXM and am not seeing any table view. I don't understand why my xcode doesn't offer this. Am I missing a plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the `object` library` here:

Also make sure you have your `Main.storyboard` file open

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The list you are looking at is file templates. You need to:

- start editing a storyboard
- pick the third item in the toolbar for the section you are typing into, which is where all the view templates are located.

Now you should find the table view you’re after and drag it into the storyboard.

Comment: I have Main.storyboard. When I type into the search bar in lower left corner, it just says "No results"

Answer (score 1):

you just selected the wrong option just select the third option object library and the start type tableview, once you get result drag and drop tableview in viewController interface and then its done